# run bash script without input

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have written a bash script which installs a number of packages, however for each consecutive package installation i am promoted with the following message:

```
After this operation, 1,006 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Is there a way of setting the default to Y so no user input is required? My script is expected to run at night without any intervention

thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC there was an "y" command ages ago ? (a simple command emitting Y<cr> on stdout, but it was ages ago)

Comment: In addition to Misch's answer, you should install all the packages in one call to apt, for better efficiency. eg instead of `for package in "${packages[@]}"; do apt-get install "$package" -y; done`; do this instead: `apt-get install "${packages[@]}" -y`

Comment: thanks for the response guys, when i run the following outside of my bash script, your solution works fine - however when with in the script it still prompts me - here is one of the packages i am attempting to install with no user intervention. sudo apt-get install -y flex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two methods come to mind. The first (and better option) is to use the options in your package manager. For example:

```
apt-get install -y [YOUR_PACKAGE]
```

if you use `apt` (type `apt-get install --help` for more help there).

The second is more of a quick-'n-dirty one...use a pipe after `yes`:

```
yes | apt-get install [YOUR_PACKAGE]
```

which always brings a smile to my face :p

The latter option also answers yes to ALL other questions, which can be handy (errors etc.) but can be risky (which is the reason those questions are there in the first place!)

Comment: thanks for the response guys, when i run the following outside of my bash script, your solution works fine - however when with in the script it still prompts me - here is one of the packages i am attempting to install with no user intervention. sudo apt-get install -y flex

Comment: Strange...that works perfectly fine for me. Could you perhaps post (a snippet of) the script in question?

Comment: how about redirecting stdin with `command arg1 < /dev/null` ?

Answer (score 4):

I think that message looks like you are using apt-get.

In that case you can use the flag `--assume-yes` or shorter: `-y`, which should automatically answer yes to that question without prompting the user

Comment: While this works for apt's questions, high priority interactive debconf prompts will still appear.

Comment: There is also --force-yes. I don't know if there will be no questions at all if you use it, but the manual says 'It should not be used except in very special situations. Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system!'

Comment: does not apply to debconf, whose questions may not be "yes or no". Consider MySQL where debconf prompts to set a root password for MySQL.

Comment: thanks for the response guys, when i run the following outside of my bash script, your solution works fine - however when with in the script it still prompts me - here is one of the packages i am attempting to install with no user intervention. sudo apt-get install -y flex

Comment: @godzilla This works for me. I simply put your command (with a different package, because I have flex installed) in a shell script and execute it. I'm not prompted to accept the dependencies. How does your script look like?